# I would start my web browser by executing a .html file

Tags: python, html, subprocess

My Python script creates an HTML file which in turns calls Google Charts.  I would like to add a system call at the end to launch this HTML file to display the results via a web brower.

I've tried using the subprocess and system call functions but both have the same result:
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application where %1 is the name of the output file from my script with the .HTML extension.

I'm able to launch the same file from a DOS shell just by typing the file name.

What would be the correct way to accomplish this task via a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`webbrowser.open('my_file.html')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open).